# sqlite query without attach

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a database file with sqlite3 library interface. I have to execute a query on a database file through C program, which does this:

```c
sqlite3 *hSQL3;
const char *zVfs = NULL;
int rc = sqlite3_open_v2( "mydb.dbf", & hSQL3,
                (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE), zVfs );
```

My query works fine on a database file with `ATTACH` query before `SELECT` query as below,

```
ATTACH database 'D:\mydb.dbf' as db;
SELECT name office FROM db.table_name;
DETACH database db;
```

I would like to avoid `ATTACH` and `DETACH` query. How can I execute `SELECT` query on `mydb.dbf` without using `ATTACH` query?

Some thing like below,

```
SELECT name office FROM 'D:\mydb.dbf'.table_name;
```

Comment: Show your C program, especially the part that calls `sqlite3_open_v2()`.

Comment: `sqlite3  *hSQL3;`

`const char *zVfs = NULL;`

`int rc = sqlite3_open_v2( "mydb.dbf", & hSQL3, (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE), zVfs );`

Comment: Well, you already know that `sqlite3_open_v2()` wants a file name. So why don't you try to give it the name of the file you want to use?